# How do I find which debian package a stack is in?

Tags: ros, rosdeb, debian, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to search through the available ros-* debian packages to find which one contains a particular ROS stack or ROS package?  I wanted to install the image_transport_plugins stack, but the [wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport_plugins) [doesn't give me the right info](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4917).  (The base ROS Debian packages have been reorganized in Diamondback.)

I don't want to just install *all* of ROS to make sure I get the one small stack I need.  Is there some index of debian ros package contents I can search through?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9724/how-do-i-find-which-debian-package-a-stack-is-in?/) by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1351 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Debian package names can be derived from ros-ROSDISTRO-STACK-NAME

Where ROSDISTRO is boxturtle, cturtle, or diamondback

STACK-NAME is the stack name with underscores replaced with dashes.   (ala common_msgs -> common-msgs)

TO find what stack a package is inside of I usually visit the wiki page and look at the header.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if there is a ROS way, but the debian/ubuntu-way is to use apt-file.
You would need a repository with contents though.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-04-13**:
I feel like an 'apt-cache search packagename' should also return the stack to install for the package. As of now, it only seems to work for the stack name.